# Mismatch in datatype in Database level and Informatica level for taget

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a query suppose In Database one column has integer dataype but in informatica it is allotted as Varchar by mistake for Target.

example data from source is '37RR' Varchar .

What will happen ?

Do all records get rejected OR after encountering '37RR' records will get rejected.

And when i am changing the datatype of column to integer also in Informatica it is loading 37 in target not rejecting the record.

Answer (score 0):

Informatica is unaware of what's really there in the Database. It will simply try to insert `37RR` into the specified target column via the used connector. Here, a number of things may happen - depending on settings on different layers:

- DB may reject the whole row
- DB may do an implicit conversion and trim the data, hence inserting the `36`
- Connector may get the error message from DB and forward it to Integration Service
- Connector may not fet the error message or fail to forward it to IS

Best way is to fix it and never rely on any implicit conversions. And if you need, test your setup to verify system behavior in the logs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .
I tried it and when ever informatica encounters this it is dropping the inline records and also i cannot found them in bad file .however session is succeeded and monitor showing all records got inserted but in DB the count is different.
Where can i find those missing records.

Comment: That depends on the connector setup. If it did not forward the rejection, then Informatica is unaware of that, so it cannot fail the session - there's no ground. But do check your 'Stop on errors' property in session and make sure it's not set to zero - that would mean session should not consider DB errors as reason for failure.

Comment: Yes DB doing implicit conversion .
Source is Varchar and target is Integer . Also same in database and infrormatica level.
Why informatica not throwing conversion error .
for example '3784RR'

Comment: Informatica is not throwing an error, because Informatica is not doing the conversion. And it either doesn't get any error information or is configured to discard it.

Comment: Is there any any way we can handle it .
i have used IS_NUMBER but again after if input is not number i am getting 0 in Target.
implicit conversion :
'32R' -- 32
'RR'-- 0

Comment: Of course there is! But it depends on what you want to do. In this case I'd suggest going back and reviewing the requirements.

Comment: i don't to load the records which are not in integer .
As implicit conversion is taking place in DB so I am unable to avoid it.