# Not getting Error on Conversion String to Integer in Informatica

Tags: mysql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

My source has string and Target has integer column.
Suppose my source data is 'RRRR' .
Here it is loading 0 in the target with no errors..
Why informatica is not throwing conversion error.
Didn't provided any default value.

Comment: Like I tried to explain in your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61007451/mismatch-in-datatype-in-database-level-and-informatica-level-for-taget) Informatica DOES NOT do any conversion in this case. Hence there is no error in INFORMATICA. It's on your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an expression to identify if incoming record is integer or string.
Donot load if check fails.